# como ler este escopo?

Tags: php

Preciso ver detalhadamente, pelo que eu li e o seguinte:

> SE A VARIAVEL $NAME ESTIVER PRESENTE E $NAME NAO ESTIVER VAZIA EXECUTAR: ADICIONAR NA DATA BASE COLUNA "AVEIME" LOGIN, E SENHA AS VARIAVEIS $NAME E $PASSWORD, MEDIANTE $RESULTADO_USUARIO, SE EXECUTADO $RESULTADO_USUARIO EXECUTAR  .. AI JA NAO SEI MAIS... PODEM ME AJUDAR?

```
if (isset($name) && !empty($name)){

$result_usuario = "INSERT INTO aveime (login, senha) VALUES ('$name', '$password')";

$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);

    if($resultado_usuario){

            $_SESSION['id'] = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

            header("Location: form2.php");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($resultado_usuario){

    $_SESSION['id'] = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    header("Location: form2.php");
}
```

Se o registro foi salvo no banco com sucesso (`if($resultado_usuario)`) então pega o ID inserido na última consulta ao banco (`mysqli_insert_id($conn)`) e salva ele numa session (`$_SESSION['id']`), então redireciona o usuário para a página form2.php (`header("Location: form2.php")`)

Ps: caso a session não esteja salvando o id, verifique se você está inicializando a sessão no início do arquivo com `session_start();`